# Floating a table column correctly

Tags: css, tablelayout

[image]

How can I achieve the table layout pictured above using css?

Comment: This is open to debate and i'll though I tend to agree with you its still a valid question

Comment: If the children `div`s are floated. Make sure the parent is also floated. If you're trying to achieve it to be centered, you need to use another wrapper `div` for the centered effect.

Comment: Thanks, managed this with answer below but thanks for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Col 1" needs `position:absolute;` to be able to float on the other elements

Comment: Thanks, should have been obvious to me